# When accessing the same route, useEffect is not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I implemented the API to run when the screen is accessed using useEffect in Next.js v10.

The code is simply written as below.

```
...
const fetchAPI = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.get({ .... })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  fetchAPI()
}, [])
...
```

When I first access, the API of the useEffect runs normally.

However, if I go to another screen and then access the screen again, useEffect does not work.

This is the same for useEffect on other screens.

Can I run useEffect every time I access the screen?

Currently, the dependency is set to `[]`, but if `[]` is removed at all, the application stops.

Which solution will help me?

No matter how much I look, I can't find a problem like this.

---

**I solved that problem and wrote the answer below.**

Comment: Sounds like the screen component is not being unmounted between navigations. Your `useEffect` will only run on mount.  Navigation libraries don't necessarily unmount component's when a new screen is accessed. Show your navigation component.

Comment: It really depends on how your navigation works, if it HIDES the component - your useEffect will not work, if it re-renders the components - it will work.
If it somehow hides it, you should have some prop or state which says "hidden:true" for example, so you could useEffect on that

Comment: @Adam Oh, It's my fault. this problem is 'Cache'. Previously, if there was data in the cache, the data was displayed without requesting a new server.
I realized that and changed it to make network requests unconditionally regardless of cache.

Comment: @NikitaChayka I can only mention one person, so I write it down again. Now it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### I solved that problem and wrote the answer below.

The problem occurred in the `cache`.

The previously implemented method does not request a new server if data remains in the cache, and the remaining data is used as it is.

So, even if you access the page anew, the same data is displayed, and there is no change in the network tab.

`So I realized that and changed it to make a network request every time a page is accessed, regardless of the cache.`

And it's working fine.

Sorry for asking such a stupid question...

Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: Can you elaborate on `changed it to make a network request every time`

Comment: me too , i want to know as i am having the same issues

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js version 13, there's an enhanced focus on caching through the app router mechanism. Detailed information on this can be found in the [official Next.js documentation on caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching).

**Key Points to Consider**:

1. **Caching Behavior in Next.js**:

   - Next.js caches both static and dynamic content when using the `fetch` method. Additionally, the framework advises the browser to cache results from client-side fetch operations.
2. **Potential Conflict with Custom Caching**:

   - Implementing custom caching logic within your code could introduce conflicts. This was a noticeable aspect in one of my projects.

**Recommendations for Your Scenario**:

1. **Browser Cache Check**:

   - First, ensure that the issue isn't arising due to the browser's caching mechanism. In Chrome's developer tools, navigate to `Network conditions` -> `Caching` -> Check `[✓]Disable cache`.
   - [Chrome DevTools - Disabling Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxmF2.png)
2. **Examine Local Storage & Other Storage Mechanisms**:

   - In Chrome DevTools' `Application` tab, you can inspect elements like local storage, cookies, and cache APIs.
   - You can expand each option to view its contents. If necessary, right-click a particular storage and select `Delete` to clear it. Do note that caching mechanisms, especially those that depend on secure contexts, might only work on the dev machine with `http://localhost` or on other machine with `https://`. This is important when testing on mobile locally with `http://myComputerName.local`
3. **Check for Overlooked Logic in Your Code**:

   - Ensure no crucial segments of your code logic were missed or inadvertently omitted.
4. **Utilizing React Server Component for Dynamic Rendering**:

   - If your page structure uses React Server Component, consider introducing `searchParams` to ensure dynamic rendering (see https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional):

   ```js
   // Inside dynamicPage/page.js
   import { myClientComponent } from './_components/my-client-component';

   export default async function Page({searchParams}) {
       ...
       return (
           <>
               <myClientComponent />
           </>
       );
   }
   ```

   ```
   // dynamicPage/_components/my-client-component.js
   'use client';

   import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

   export const myClientComponent = () => {
       const [data, setData] = useState(null);

       useEffect(() => {
           setData(new Date().toISOString());
       }, []);

       return <>{data}</>;
   }
   ```
5. **Deployment Considerations**:

   - If your application is deployed via Vercel, you might benefit from navigating to `Project Settings` -> `Data Caches` -> `Purge Cache`. This ensures any residues from earlier code deployments are eradicated.

---

Hope these blood and sweat I learnt from my project can help someone